# I am trying to pull product information from Keepa into a google sheet using IMPORTXML

Tags: web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to automatically pull a few pieces of data from Keepa on Amazon products to a google sheet using IMPORTXML. I have very little programming experience so honestly I don't exactly know what I'm doing. I need to pull stuff like sales rank, Amazon price, and New price.

From the research I've done I think part of the problem I'm running into is that all the information is filled in by java therefore isn't in the html to be able to be pulled using IMPORTXML. I'm copying the Xpath to try to get it to find the right place look.

```
=IMPORTXML("https://keepa.com/#!product/1-B00066LORG","//*[@id='borderLayout_eGridPanel']/div[1]/div/div/div[3]/div[3]/div/div/div[1]/div[2]/span/span")
```

I want it to pull that value into the sheet and simply put it into a cell. Most of the time I am getting a #N/A Error that the imported content is empty. Any help will be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: How are you getting on with the Google Sheets problem? Have you resolved it, or are you still looking for help?

Comment: I have solved the problem, I ended up going with camelcamelcamel instead thanks.